# how to set variables interactively for ediff

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I'm using ediff mode, and I'd like to split the windows horizontally instead of the vertical default. The ediff manual says this can be done interactively.

> ediff-split-window-function
>
> Controls the way you want the window be split between file-A and
>   file-B (and file-C, if applicable). It defaults to the vertical split
>   (split-window-vertically, but you can set it to
>   split-window-horizontally, if you so wish. Ediff also lets you switch
>   from vertical to horizontal split and back interactively.
>
> Note that if Ediff detects that all the buffers it compares are
>   displayed in separate frames, it assumes that the user wants them to
>   be so displayed and stops splitting windows. Instead, it arranges for
>   each buffer to be displayed in a separate frame. You can switch to the
>   one-frame mode by hiding one of the buffers A/B/C.
>
> You can also swap the windows where buffers are displayed by typing ~

I've tried using  M-x set-variable to set this variable to split-window-horiztonally, but that did not change the layout. I want to do this interactively, I know I can set it as default in .emacs but I dont want to do that at this stage.

Comment: If you use `set-variable` be sure you spell the value correctly. Another way to do it interactively, which is more sure (it does everything that might need to be done) is to use `M-x customize-option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do this interactively, I know I can set it as default in .emacs but I dont want to do that at this stage.

Type <kbd>|</kbd>

(n.b. that's the `|` pipe character; as opposed to `I` or `l` or `1`.)

You should probably *also* type <kbd>?</kbd> and review the information it shows you.